# How can I display a random word?

Tags: database, vb.net, dictionary

I wanted to find a way to make a hangman game, but that can use a large amount of words. Since it is not efficient to have x different cases, I was wondering if there is any way to display a random word. I tried looking for dictionaries, but all I found was a dictionary type. I am a beginner, so simplified answers would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case would be using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` and then getting random line using `Random`.

Comment: Great! Where should I place the text file?

Comment: What do you mean by _placing the text file_? `Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(pathWhereYourFileIs)`

Comment: I want to make the location of the test file relative to the position of the program directory, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

create a text file with one word per line.
Then you read in the file and assign one string to the current line.
Then you add the string to a dynamic list or array.
now you have your word list. then simply create a random number called pos from 0 to n-1 where n is the size if the array ( number of words)
pos now is the index of the word, you will then get from your words array.